# rails Remotipart form with Firefox doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, firefox, upload, remotipart

I have this form, which submits well on Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox :

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote=> true, :html => { :id => "upload_avatar" , :multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :delete_avatar_pic%>
<%= f.file_field :avatar, :accept => "image/*"%>
<% end %>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Jeremie

Comment: Maybe javascript is disabled in your firefox ? If it's enabled, then good way to debug it in firefox is installing the fireBug. Then you could monitor your request and see what's happening.

Comment: actually the forms submits well but the file_field remains empty even if I select a file to upload. javascript is enabled